# Range Error(index): invalid value: valid value range is empty

Tags: android, arrays, flutter, android-studio, dart

im trying to set initial value for 'title' but it keeps showing me the error: range error (index): invalid value: valid value range is empty

```
class _ProductCreateState extends State<ProductCreate> {
 final Map<String, dynamic> formData = {

   'title': '',
   'description': '',
   'price': 0.0,
   'image': 'images/images (2).jpeg'
 };
    final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

 Widget _buildTitleTextField() {
   return Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
     child: TextFormField(
       initialValue: widget.stuff[0]['title'],
       decoration: InputDecoration(
         labelText: 'Product Title',
       ),
validator: (String? value) {
if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
           //   (||) means or
           return 'Title is required and should be 5+ characters';
         }
       },

       onSaved: (String? value) {
         setState(() {
           formData['title'] = value!;
           // titleValue = value!;
         });
       },
     ),
   );
 }
```

Comment: Can you please share or tell us what is your widget.stuff ?

Comment: List<Map<String,dynamic>> _stuff;

Comment: stuff is a list in the code

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing the widget.stuff[0] directly please do handle for the null as well as is that the array is empty in the buildTextFormField method.